# Pandas Datetimeindex with numpy.maximum gives error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'm experiencing an error that is possibly a bug in pandas (v. 0.22 on Windows, Python version 3.6.3), or rather in its interaction with NumPy (v. 1.14), but I wonder if I'm missing something more profound.

Here's the issue: if I have two `Datetimeindex` objects of the same length and I use `np.maximum` between them, the output is as expected:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
v1 = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-01', '2018-01-02', '2018-01-03'])
v2 = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2017-01-01', '2017-01-02', '2019-01-03'])
np.maximum(v1, v2)
```

returns the elementwise maximum:

> DatetimeIndex(['2017-01-01', '2018-01-02', '2019-01-03'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

However, if I try to only use one element of the two, I get an error:

```
np.maximum(v1, v2[0])
```

> pandas_libs\tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib._Timestamp.**richcmp**()
>
> TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'int'

Two workarounds that work, but both are rather nasty to write, are either to use slicing or to explicitly convert to pydatetime:

```
np.maximum(v1, v2[:1])
```

> DatetimeIndex(['2017-01-01', '2018-01-02', '2018-01-03'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

or:

```
v1.to_pydatetime() - v2[0].to_pydatetime()
```

> array([datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0),
>          datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 2, 0, 0),
>          datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 3, 0, 0)], dtype=object)

The first workaround is actually quite weird, because doing `v2 - v1[0]` works correctly, while `v2 - v1[:1]` gives an error (rather as expected this time, since the two resulting time series have unaligned indices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to convert to a `pd.Series`, and then use [`pd.Series.clip`](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.Series.clip.html):

```
pd.Series(v1).clip(v2[0])

# 0   2017-01-01
# 1   2018-01-02
# 2   2018-01-03
# dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the cleanest solution (although maybe the complete answer should be pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.Series(v1).clip(v2[0]))), so I'll accept it. However, I still feel that if operations like "+" and "<" are supported between DatetimeIndex and Timestamp objects, an elementwise maximum should also work...

Comment: @MarcoSpinaci. agreed. I would have though all the common functionality available to `pd.Series` would also be available to `pd.DatetimeIndex`, but it appears not!

Answer (score 0):

```
TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'long'
```

This is the error that you will get on using this -

```
np.maximum(v1, v2[0])
```

Why you are getting this error? Just think about it. The answer is in the type error itself. You are comparing 2 things whose typecast is different.

For comparing with a single element in 2nd time stamp you can use -

```
print(np.maximum(v1, v2[1:2]))
print(np.maximum(v1, v2[:1]))
print(np.maximum(v1, v2[2:3]))
```

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Apologies, but although I can read the error, I still don't get why it *should* be so. If I have an index/Series/etc. done by int, float, str, or the like, when I select one object of it I still obtain an int/float/str and can compare it with the original series. However, Datetimeindex is essentially an int, like np.datetime64, but if I select an element of it it gets converted to Timestamp and that breaks comparison with the original series. That's handled correctly by overloaded pandas operations like "+" and "<" so I'd expect it also to work with np.maximum, except it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of `np.maximum` the behaviour is expected. note that the operation `v1[0]` is called **selection** and returns a **single TimeStamp** while `v[:1]` is known ***slicing*** and returns an array.

here is part of `help(np.maximum)` output

```
|  
 |  op(X, Y, out=None)
 |  Apply `op` to `X` and `Y` elementwise. May "broadcast" to make
 |  the shapes of `X` and `Y` congruent.
 |  
 |  The broadcasting rules are:
 |  
 |  * Dimensions of length 1 may be prepended to either array.
 |  * Arrays may be repeated along dimensions of length 1.
 |  
 |  Parameters
 |  ----------
 |  X : array_like
 |      First input array.
 |  Y : array_like
 |      Second input array.
 |  out : array_like
 |      An array to store the output. Must be the same shape as the
 |      output would have.
 |  
 |  Returns
 |  -------
 |  r : array_like
 |      The return value; if out is provided, `r` will be equal to out.
```

Comment: Actually I think that, if anything, the help says that it should work... If I work elementwise, e.g. np.maximum(v1[0], v2[0]), I get no error and the correct answer; similarly if doing something like np.where(v1 < v2[0], v2[0], v1) although the types do get mixed up. The error comes up only when trying to mix different types (DatetimeIndex vs Timestamp) in a vectorized way through numpy.